# gcloud Object metadata supplied for destination object had no object name

Tags: gcloud

I try to rsync a local folder with a google cloud bucket. However, I get the following exception from gcloud:

`ArgumentException: Object metadata supplied for destination object had no object name.`

Does anybody now a workaround for this?

StackTrace:

`018-04-15T08:30:06.3806055Z - [2 files][  9.0 MiB/ 16.3 MiB]   69.2 KiB/s

2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806130Z DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806196Z     Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806287Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 571, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806398Z         user_project=user_project)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806489Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 319, in RunNamedCommand
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806582Z         return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806672Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 1462, in RunCommand
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3806763Z         fail_on_error=True, seek_ahead_iterator=seek_ahead_iterator)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807079Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\command.py", line 1383, in Apply
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807172Z         arg_checker, should_return_results, fail_on_error)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807263Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\command.py", line 1454, in _SequentialApply
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807353Z         worker_thread.PerformTask(task, self)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807449Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\command.py", line 2120, in PerformTask
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807540Z         results = task.func(cls, task.args, thread_state=self.thread_gsutil_api)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807636Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 1252, in _RsyncFunc
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807736Z         gzip_exts=cls.gzip_exts, preserve_posix=cls.preserve_posix_attrs)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807835Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\copy_helper.py", line 3515, in PerformCopy
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3807922Z         allow_splitting=allow_splitting, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808025Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\copy_helper.py", line 2021, in _UploadFileToObject
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808115Z         parallel_composite_upload, logger)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808208Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\copy_helper.py", line 1872, in _DelegateUploadFileToObject
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808308Z         elapsed_time, uploaded_object = upload_delegate()
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808401Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\copy_helper.py", line 2004, in CallNonResumableUpload
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808489Z         gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded_file)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808591Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\copy_helper.py", line 1583, in _UploadFileToObjectNonResumable
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808684Z         fields=UPLOAD_RETURN_FIELDS, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808778Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\cloud_api_delegator.py", line 287, in UploadObject
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3808970Z         gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809064Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\gcs_json_api.py", line 1376, in UploadObject
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809148Z         gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809245Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\gcs_json_api.py", line 1152, in _UploadObject
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809332Z         ValidateDstObjectMetadata(object_metadata)
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809425Z       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\cloud_api_helper.py", line 40, in ValidateDstObjectMetadata
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809534Z         'Object metadata supplied for destination object had no object name.')
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809621Z     ArgumentException: ArgumentException: Object metadata supplied for destination object had no object name.
2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809696Z

2018-04-15T08:30:06.3809769Z ArgumentException: Object metadata supplied for destination object had no object name.`

Used version on Windows:

`Google Cloud SDK 197.0.0
bq 2.0.31
core 2018.04.06
gsutil 4.30`

Answer (score 0):

The above error, and per our discussion at this [issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78046689), is specific to using [gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) on Windows, and due to using forward-slash `./` rather than using backslash `.\` in both command line and Powershell. It could be related to the fact that Windows [MS-DOS uses backslashes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/06/24/why-is-the-dos-path-character/) to separate directories in file paths `C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory`, and not forward-slashes like other operating systems. Hence, the following command should work:

```
 $gsutil rsync -d .\ gs://bucketname/folder
```